# Is the selection of codomain restricted by domain?

Tags: functions

When we define a function we give the domain and the codomain. My question is if we have a function like:

$$f:\left.\begin{array}{ll}\Bbb R \to \Bbb R\\ x \mapsto x ^ 2\end{array}\right.$$

what is the point of defining the codomain? I mean if we define the codomain as the set of integers then shouldn't we omit the mapping $ x \mapsto x^2 $ ? For example $f(2.3)$ isn't a member of the set of integers. So is the codomain restricted by domain only when the mapping is given by an equation?

Comment: You can't define the codomain of this function as the integers, for the reason you've provided. But you can certainly define the codomain as the non-negative reals, or the complex numbers, or any other set containing the non-negative reals. It's only surjective if the codomain is the non-negative reals.